# Generating segfault from a custom syscall

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals

I'm doing `copy_to_user()` from a syscall.

How can I get it to generate a segfault or sigbus on error, as if userspace was trying to access the same memory?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Yunnosch  I'm all for MCVEs, but I'm basically asking how to trigger as segfault corresponding to address X from kernel space.  Simple question with, I'm assuming, a single-line answer. Posting the several pages of code required to set up a linux build, wire up a syscall, compile it, run it in a virtual machine, and have the virtual machine execute a user-space test program seems a little bit like an overkill.

Comment: What about `kill(getpid(), SIGSEGV);`?

Comment: Usually, the syscall should return -EFAULT on such an error, are you sure you want to break with this pattern? Otherwise, have a look at `send_sig_info()`

Comment: Point conceeded. I was aiming for some lines of code which give some context of the concept. Something like a few lines of pseudo code (embedded as comments inside actual code) which illustrate the situation in which you want to trigger and some reasoning. I wanted you to provide a differebnt view on your problem, in addition to the prose (which to my taste is a bit short). For example, I do not get why you want to give the fake impression that some userspace code has misbehaved, while actually kernel space had some kind of problem. I admit that MCVE is the wrong term for that.

Comment: Because I was aware that my confusion was just based on my (mis-)understanding of your prose, I wanted the different angle, without describing my interpretation. (Funny that I got three people agreeing to the request for MCVE, but that is no excuse for my mistake.)

Comment: @Yunnosch It seemed straightforward and made sense to me. If a userspace function that writes to a pointed-to-address gets an unwritable address, it segfaults. I don't see why a syscall should behave differently.

Comment: I was aware that the problem is mostly with me, that is why I tried (unsuccessfully) to ask indirectly for more info. I only mentioned in order to admit my mistake. You got some comments from people who were less confused and 6 other obviously agreeing with you. Do not mind me (no sarcasm).

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally speaking, you can't. Unless you're planning on rewriting the kernel.

When the kernel accesses user-mode addresses it uses a safe form, usually `copy_from_user`, `copy_to_user`, `get_user`, ... - as you mentioned. These macros have a return value the kernel checks for, and in most cases will return `-EFAULT`.

Then, usually comes libc and adjusts the return value to fit the `man` page - meaning it sets `errno` if the result is erroneous (depending on which syscall was called).

For example, a common snippet in the kernel goes as following:

```
if (unlikely(copy_from_user(&pos, offset, sizeof(loff_t))))
    return -EFAULT;
```

(taken from `sendfile64` syscall's implementation at fs/read_write.c)

As you see, when the kernel fails to read from usermode, it returns `-EFAULT`.

Given that it is possible to pass more than one pointer to some syscalls, it may be impossible to figure out which one caused the `-EFAULT`. So there isn't a generic usermode way to send `SIGSEGV`s upon a checked invalid memory access on the kernel's behalf.

---

If, however, you're writing a kernel syscall yourself, and you want to trigger a signal, that's not difficult at all. I haven't digged too much in the kernel, but calling something among the lines of `send_sig_info` (or another suitable function in kernel/signal.c) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. `send_sig_info` is straightforward but I'd like to know how to fill in the info struct, what signal to send (I believe SIGSEGV and SIGBUS are the options), assuming the memory access should behave the same as if it originated from userspace.